# Why does Ruby not have boolean class, instead using TrueClass and FalseClass?

Tags: ruby

A Ruby book mentioned that `true` is a singleton instance of `TrueClass`. I'm wondering why Ruby does not have the boolean class which supports two variables like other languages usually do?